# Extracting Text from HTML Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nlp, nltk

Hi I am trying extract text from a HTML using BeautifulSoup function in python- it runs well but I am not getting what I need. My code is of the following:

```
url = "http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/2284783.stm"
html = urlopen(url).read()
raw = BeautifulSoup(html).get_text()
```

Python console reports the following and I do not understand the problem and would appreciate the help.

```
raw = BeautifulSoup(html).get_text()
C:/Users/muradz14/.spyder-py3/raw.py:1: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 1 of the file C:/Users/muradz14/.spyder-py3/raw.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just a warning. It's pretty self-explanatory, but there is some small chance that the code could behave differently with different parsers, so the warning is saying that you might want to specify what you use. You can do as it suggests like this:
`raw = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml").get_text()`

Note that some systems have different parsers. For me, it's `features="html.parser"`

Comment: I have done  that and your way again the raw text seem to have html tags still

Comment: It was unclear from your original question that that was your issue. There will be html tags in the text because you are downloading the html from that URL with `get_text()`. Try something like this `raw = BeautifulSoup(html,features="html.parser")` `print(raw.title.string)`.

Read the documentation here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/